# Analysing correlation between two (or more) categorical variables?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data

**Context:** I ran a survey where I asked one person to qualitatively assess multiple wines. They was asked to choose one or more adjective to describe the taste, the smell (non-dichotomous categorical) of each wine. They was also asked to select one (out of four) evaluation of the strength (dichotomous categorical) for each wine.

Below is an example of results I obtained. The number in each cell represents the number of different wines that matches both metrics.

```
                     |Taste                                        |Smell                                       |Strength                         
                     |fruity     fleshy     full-bodied none of the|red fruits nuts       earth      none of the|very strong strong    mild      very mild  
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Taste     fruity     |          9                                  |                                            |                                 
          fleshy     |          4          9                       |                                            |                                 
          full-bodied|          2          4          5            |                                            |                                 
          none of the|          0          0          0           5|                                            |                                 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Smell     red fruits |          3          3          0           2|          6                                 |                                
          nuts       |          2          2          1           3|          1          7                      |                                 
          earth      |          4          4          2           2|          2          3          8           |                                 
          none of the|          2          2          3           1|          0          0          0          5|                                 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Strength  very strong|          3          1          2           0|          0          2          1          2|          4                      
          strong     |          2          2          0           1|          4          0          1          0|          0          4           
          mild       |          3          3          1           2|          1          2          3          2|          0          0          6
          very mild  |          1          2          1           2|          1          3          3          0|          0          0          0          5
```

Examples:

- 2 wines were considered having a *full-bodied* (left) and *fruity* (top) taste.
- 9 wines were considered having a *fruity* (left and top) taste. Note that, because the expert could choose more than one taste (and more than one smell, but only one strength) per wine, the 2 wines mentioned above are include in the 9 here mentioned.

(There are 19 wines in total)

**Issue:** I want to know wether some of the values/variables are correlated or not.

- Either between two values of a single variable, e.g.:

  > *Fleshy* and *full bodied* tastes are significantly correlated.
- Or between values of different variables; e.g.:

  > The *fruity* taste is significantly correlated with the *red fruit* smell.

**Question:** Which test should I use in such context? Is there a difference between dichotomous and non-dichotomous variables?

Comment: Please explain what the numbers in this table represent.

Comment: @whuber done. Thank you for the advice, it's indeed important.

Comment: It looks like you have a burt table. Look into correspondence analysis: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200905/how-can-one-interpret-the-stata-output-for-multiple-correspondence-analysis or search this site for visualization of contingency tables.  Very few posts here about Burt tables.